# generate notification with webhook

Tags: c#, webhooks

I have a (c#) server and client with webhook implementation.
I have a custom authentication handler to authenticate client receivers when they subscribe for events.
This works ok.

Now, I want to trigger an event from inside the server's code on some condition. At that moment, I call method:

this.NotifyAsync()

located on source code:

```
namespace System.Web.Http
public static class ApiControllerExtensions
public static Task<int> NotifyAsync(this ApiController controller, string action, object data)
```

Problem is that this call to NotifyAsync() will check that there is an authenticated user, which is not the case because is the server itself triggering this action..

Did I need to generate an AuthenticationTicket() from inside servers code in order to trigger webhook notification or there is other way to do it ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

just calling NotifyAllAsync() !!! no authentication required here and it will send notification to all clients...